# Proving an inequality of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, lp-spaces

I am currently reading a paper that claims the following fact:

> Let $X$, $Y$ be $L^2$ random variables on some probability space. The $L^2$ norm is denoted by $\| \cdot \|_{2}$. Then there exists $C>0$ such that
>   \begin{eqnarray}
> && \mathbb{E} \bigg[ \mathbf{1}_{\{ |Y| \geq \|Y\|^{1/2}_2 \}} (1+ |X| + |Y|)|Y| \bigg] \\
> & \leq & C \|Y\|_2 \bigg( \|Y\|_2 + \sqrt{\|Y\|_2} + \sup_{A: \mathbb{P}(A) \leq \|Y\|_2} \mathbb{E}[|X|^2 \mathbf{1}_A]^{1/2} \bigg).
> \end{eqnarray}

It seems to involve the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, applying to the terms $ \mathbf{1}_{\{|Y| \geq \|Y\|^{1/2}_2\}}(1+|X|+|Y|)$ and $|Y|$. But I don't see how the $L^2$ norm of the first term can be bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can estimate each term separately. Observe the following:
$$
\Bbb E\left[1_{\{ |Y| \geq \|Y\|^{1/2}_2 \}}|Y|\right]\le \Bbb E\left[1_{\{ |Y| \geq \|Y\|^{1/2}_2 \}}\frac{|Y|^2}{\|Y\|_2^{1/2}}\right]\le\|Y\|_2^{3/2},
$$
$$
\Bbb E\left[1_{\{ |Y| \geq \|Y\|^{1/2}_2 \}}|Y|^2\right]\le \|Y\|_2^2,
$$

$$
\Bbb P(|Y| \geq \|Y\|^{1/2}_2)=\Bbb P(|Y|^2 \geq \|Y\|_2)\le \frac{\Bbb E|Y|^2}{\|Y\|_2}=\|Y\|_2,
$$ and
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\Bbb E\left[1_{\{ |Y| \geq \|Y\|^{1/2}_2 \}}|X||Y|\right]^2&\le& \Bbb E\left[1_{\{ |Y| \geq \|Y\|^{1/2}_2 \}}|X|^2\right]\Bbb E\left[1_{\{ |Y| \geq \|Y\|^{1/2}_2 \}}|Y|^2\right]\\
&\le&\sup_{A:\Bbb P(A)\le \|Y\|_2}\Bbb E[X^2 1_A]\cdot \|Y\|^2_2
\end{eqnarray}$$ by Cauchy-Schwarz. This gives
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{E} \left[ 1_{\{ |Y| \geq \|Y\|^{1/2}_2 \}} (1+ |X| + |Y|)|Y| \right] \le \|Y\|_2\left(\|Y\|_2+\|Y\|_2^{1/2}+\left(\sup_{A:\Bbb P(A)\le \|Y\|_2}\Bbb E[X^2 1_A]\right)^{1/2}\right)
\end{eqnarray}
$$ as desired.